# Apache Tomcat is good with MySQL or Jetty or Glassfish?

Tags: java, tomcat, glassfish, webserver, jetty

I have developed WebService using **Restlet API in Java for iPhone/iPad** devices.

Our server is **Linux CentOS, 2GB RAM, 14GB disk space**.

I am using **Apache Tomcat 6.0.35 and MySQL 5.1** database.

These users may have many concurrent users say 100000 for example.

So my question is that Apache Tomcat and MySQL is best combination for it or I should change the combination like **Jetty or Glassfish or any other web server** and **MySQL or other database** ?

But I am worried about the performance with the combinations.

So please guide me on this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: No configuration on that hardware is going to serve 100000 concurrent users.

Comment: @thatidiotguy, Right now I am not considering any configurations. And also I dont know what configurations I need to work on hardware?

Comment: I'm no specialist but I'm not even sure if 100000 concurent users will work on any single machine. You probably need a small cluster for that. Depends on how complex/expensive a single call to your API is. And I'm not even talking about the internet connection required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No configuration on that hardware is going to serve 100000 concurrent users. And that is just such a huge number. Unless you have the next google on your hands, i think you are going to be looking at most a few concurrent users at a time, which depending on what you are doing, should be easily manageable.

Personally, I use tomcat because I think it is a little "lighter" than glassfish. Glassfish though has a lot more configuration available in its administration console.

EDIT:

Apparently Jetty can indeed be used as a production ready application server. See the comment below. My experience was purely using it for testing, but it was a good experience!

Comment: Thanks thatidiotguy for explaining the good scenario.

Comment: Jetty is definitely usable in production. See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Jetty+Powered.